# Use Like Action with different Object Type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

We are using Open Graph Actions on a content consumption portal where user can like an Article. We want to associate a Custom Like Action with the like button also. The issue is that as per new FB Guidelines we should not create custom actions for any action which is built it and the built in action is associated with Object type 'Object'. How can we associate it with 'Article' which is our custom object and how can we call the Post API so that the story comes like "XYZ liked an Article" rather than "XYZ liked an Object"

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Built-in Likes is exactly what you are looking for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/

You create a Like action and then associate it with the Object that you choose!

Comment: I Dont see the option of changing the Object with Like Action. The Moment we create Like Action, it is automatically associated with object type "Object"